# UITableview with more than One Custom UITableViewCell with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, chat

I want to use more then one custom cells for my cell application.
Can anyone suggest me the approach do it.
TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create and use custom prototype table cells in xamarin ios using storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072250/create-and-use-custom-prototype-table-cells-in-xamarin-ios-using-storyboard)

Comment: There are already plenty of guides online, and questions on this forum with answers relating to your question. Also you have shown no examples of things that you've tried already. This question is also a very very short version duplicate of a few others. It's unlikely you will get the kind of answer you need.